# Walmart DVS API not returning products

Tags: php, api, curl

I have been working with the walmart API for the marketplace and have everything working. Now on DVS it is not working for me. I am getting authenticated and everything but when I try to pull a list of my current listing it tells me nothing found. the same call to the marketplace works fine.
Any ideas what might be missing?

**I'm using curl in PHP:**

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $apiheaders);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

*GET URL: https://api-gateway.walmart.com/v3/items?limit=10*

**HEADERS:**

```
    [0] => WM_SVC.NAME: Drop Ship Vendor Services
    [1] => WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: xxxxxx
    [2] => WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP:xxxxxx
    [3] => WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE:xxxxxx
    [4] => WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE: xxxxxxx
    [5] => WM_CONSUMER.ID: xxxxxxxx
    [6] => Accept: application/xml
```

**I get back:**

```
[error] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [code] => CONTENT_NOT_FOUND.GMP_ITEM_QUERY_API
            [description] => No item found
            [info] => Requested content could not be found.
            [severity] => INFO
            [category] => APPLICATION
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Walmart support and apparently the V3 items AP/I is not yet up at all. 
Their reply:

> Thank you for the mail, Unfortunately GET Item API is currently
>   unavailable to use hence you are getting Content Not Found response.
>
> We are going to update developer portal soon with updated API detail

Comment: hi, did you get any response? im still getting the same error